# How should I decode this string

Tags: python, string, encoding

I'm trying to read a ".cnt" file using Python. My understanding is that it encodes information from an EEG. I read the file in a standard way:

```
file = open("PICS2s8.cnt","rb") #I get the same results with 'r' instead of 'rb'
data = file.readlines()
```

When I check the first line of the file, I see:

```
'Version 3.0\x00\xe3\x00J\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00UU\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0013/10/05\x00\x0011:28:07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00--------\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00--------\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf2\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8b\x02 \x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xf4\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00zD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\xcc\xcc\xbd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\xcc\xcc\xbd\x9a\x99\x99?\x00\x00H\xc2\x00\x00HB\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0\xc2\x00\x00\xf0B\xcd\xcc\xcc\xbd#\xdb\x99?\xcd\xcc\xcc\xbd#\xdb\x99?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\xcc\xcc\xbd\x9a\x99\x99?\x00--------\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00--------\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00--------\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x96\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00ffF@\xc8\x00d\x00\x9c\xff\xf4\x01ffF@\x8f\xc2\xf5<\x00\x00--------\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00--------\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfa?\x10\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa2p}B\xb5\x1e\x8eA\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc7\xfc\xff?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xe4\xc8I\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00PO2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00)\\\xa7C\xd3\xcd3C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x89A\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x00\x00\x15t\x84?O1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00ff6C/\xbd4C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x89A\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x01\x00\x16\xf0\x83?M2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x90\xc2\xf5@\x83\xe0/C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x89A\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x02\x00K9\x84?PZ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xebQ\x80C\x1b\x8f\x1aC\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x89A\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x03\x00\x15t\x84?P4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00)\\\xa7C\xfa\xbe\x1aC\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x89A\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x04\x00\xdc\xbd\x84?CP4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00R\xb8\xa6CZd\xfdB\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x89A\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x05\x00H\xea\x84?P8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x90\xc2\xcdC\xfa\xbe\x1aC\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x89A\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x06\x00\x15t\x84?C4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x90\xc2\xa5CJ\x0c\xc3B\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x89A\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x07\x00Q\xc4\x83?TP8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xa4p\xcdCZd\xfdB\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x89A\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x08\x00\xf8G\x84?T8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x1e\xcdCJ\x0c\xc3B\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x89A\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\t\x00\x1em\x83?P7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00q=\xcaB\xfa\xbe\x1aC\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x89A\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00"\n'
```

I'm afraid I don't really know how to begin making sense of this. I'm confused by the mix of ascii string values and byte values. I've tried:

```
data[0].decode('utf-8')
```

and

```
data[0].decode('utf-16')
```

but both raised errors.

I've also tried

```
from struct import unpack, calcsize
file.seek(0)
chunk = file.read(calcsize('25c'))
read_chunk = unpack('25c',chunk)
```

and gotten the result:

```
('V', 'e', 'r', 's', 'i', 'o', 'n', ' ', '3', '.', '0', '\x00', '\xe3', '\x00', 'J', '\x04', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x02', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00')
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: Binary formats are not limited to non-textual information. The `Version 3.0` part is just textual info in a binary file.

Comment: `data[0]` is just *one byte* and UTF-16 would expect to find multiple bytes, so yes, that raises an exception. It is not UTF data.

Comment: If it is a Continuous EEG file, have you checked http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/eeg/ ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - data[0] is many bytes - It's the first line of the file. Thanks for the link to dataformats. It looks helpful...

Comment: Where's this `read` function coming from? Did you mean `open`?

Comment: @user2357112 - Oops ... you're right.

Answer (score 0):

It is a binary format with embedded ASCII strings. It is a proprietary format, you'd have to parse the C data structures yourself using `struct` and a lot of code.

Perhaps you'd be better off converting the format or using a 3rd-party Python library; Convert the file to the `.h5` format (usable with matlab) with [this script](https://github.com/UMDLinguistics/eeg-cnt/) (Python code, uses `numpy`):

```
$ python cnt2h5 PICS2s8.cnt
```

would produce a `PICS2s8.h5` file.

Comment: I actually started with that. Since I don't have access to Matlab, I wanted a non-Matlab dependent output.  I started testing by modifying cnt2h5, so that it would just do 'load_setup', but got an info dict with key, value pairs like: 'time': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'taskfile': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00--------' I suspect I need to talk to the folks who generated this file, to ensure I know what is going into it

Answer (score 0):

Hi It may be too late to answer this question but here are my finding about additional padding of \x00 characters:

When you encode any string with some block encryption methods, it adds the null padding to the string to make it contemptible/multiple of block size of the encryption technique.

For example, if your encryption mechanism is 16 byte and your string is 12 byte then the encryption mechanism will add 4 byte null padding to the string and then encrypt it. So when you decrypt it you get the additional null padding at the end of the string.

Here is some more explanation on PHP based AES encryption: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/php_aes.asp